# How to automate mobile and web app e2e tests in a single test case using WebDriverIO?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mobile-application, webdriver-io, webautomation

I am trying to automate mobile and web app tests in a single (E2E) test case using Webdriver IO. **My application is similar to Zoom where users can join the meeting through browser client and mobile app. My automation goal is after the user joins the meeting through a browser client, the mobile app should join the same meeting.** Currently, I can start both browser and mobile app automation at the same time by adding separate configuration files for the iOS app. But, I want to integrate both the test cases on a single test.

Any hints or ideas would be highly helpful and appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/7055

The issue is fixed now thanks for this question ,

Answer (score 2):

you can use the multiremote feature : https://webdriver.io/docs/multiremote/#using-wdio-testrunner

**steps:**

```
capabilities: {

    a: {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 9515,
        "path": "/",
        capabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        }
    },
    b: {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 4723,
        "path": "/wd/hub",
        capabilities: {
            "platformName": "android",
            "appium:platformVersion": "11",
            "appium:deviceName": "Android Emulator",
            "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\ApiDemos-debug.apk",
            "appium:automationName": "uiautomator2",
            "appium:avd": "2"
        }
    }
}
,

services: [["chromedriver", {
    port: 9515,
    hostname: "localhost"
}], ["appium", { port: 4723, hostname: "localhost"}]],
```

add this as capability in your wdio config file .

This will run test on both appium and browser.

you can control both the instance from your script as :

```
   await a.url("https://www.google.com")
   await b.startActivity("someactivity")
```

means, you have to call the instance by name instead of browser

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, on following this approach, is it possible to achieve the above automation use case, where browser client starts the meeting and mobile client should join the meeting using the same meeting id.?? 
  it(‘join meeting using browser and mobile’)
    MeetingPage.getStartMeetingButton.waitAndClick() //  browser starts meeting
     // fetch and save meeting id
     // mobile device should join the same meeting 
    }
Should we have a  test case like this (combined into one) ?

Comment: It's up to your team to decide if you want that , this approach allows you to do it straight forward

Comment: Yes, the requirement is to automate in this way (browser and mobile together) and I can try it using this approach ?

Comment: b has the mobile instant and a has the browser instant

Comment: Great, let me try it and post the results. Thanks

Comment: How can I access the capabilities of a and b (defined in wdio config) from my test/spec files. Importing the config file is failing too, I have checked the example file you shared, but that's not working too. Please let me know if there are any ways to execute them ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68182553/how-can-i-access-the-capabilities-of-mobile-and-browser-defined-in-same-wdio-co?noredirect=1#comment120504391_68182553